# SQL запрос

Tags: sql

Подбросили задачку. Есть таблица:

```
deb | date
100 | 1-09-2012
200 | 2-09-2012
100 | 4-09-2012
500 | 6-09-2012
```

Надо вывести сумму deb для каждого дня и двух после него.
Уже мозг сломал, но нужной функции так и не нашёл.
**UPDATE:**
Пример результата:

```
300 | 1-09-2012
200 | 2-09-2012
100 | 4-09-2012
500 | 6-09-2012
```

Comment: В зависимости от СУБД: http://sql-ex.ru/exercises/index.php?act=learn&LN=82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так?

```
select d1._date,d1.deb as TODAY, sum(d2.deb) as NEXT_2DAYS
from debs d1 
left join debs d2 on d2._date between DATE_ADD(d1._date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) and DATE_ADD(d1._date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
group by d1._date
```

Или "два после него" имеется в виду две следующие записи по времени?

**UPD** В соответствии с примером результата (сегодня и завтра):

```
select d1._date,d1.deb+IFNULL(d2.deb,0) as TODAY_AND_TOMORROW
from debs d1 
left join debs d2 on d2._date = DATE_ADD(d1._date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

В соответствии с задачей про два дня (итого за три дня - сегодня, завтра, послезавтра):

```
select d1._date,d1.deb+sum(IFNULL(d2.deb,0)) as TODAY_AND_NEXT_2DAYS
from debs d1 
left join debs d2 on d2._date between DATE_ADD(d1._date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) and DATE_ADD(d1._date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)
group by d1._date;
```

Comment: имеется ввиду, два следующих дня

Comment: пример результата не соответствует задаче. обновил ответ, выбирайте тот, что нужен.

Comment: Спасибо. Второй похож на правильный ответ. В примере результат из головы брал, потому и не сошлось.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так, можно:

```
SELECT
    `deb`+(SELECT SUM(`deb`) FROM `test` WHERE `date` > '2012-09-02' ORDER BY `date` ASC LIMIT 2) AS `sum`
FROM
    `test`
WHERE
    `date` = '2012-09-02'
```

Только обратите внимание, что я изменил формат даты на понятный MySql **Y-m-d** а не **d-m-Y** как у вас.

Comment: *для каждого дня* так не получится...